# Sqoop error while loading data from Hive to MySQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am getting sqoop error while loading data from Hive to MySQL

Error message is:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

==

```
hive > CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
id int,
name string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
'/user/cloudera/test';
```

==

vi test:

```
1       a
2       b
```

==

```
hadoop fs -put test /user/cloudera
```

==

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `foo` (`id` int(11) , `name` varchar(30) )
```

==

sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table foo -m 1 --export-dir /user/cloudera/test

==

log:

```
14/05/13 07:18:52 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
14/05/13 07:18:52 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/05/13 07:18:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `foo` AS t LIMIT 1
14/05/13 07:18:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `foo` AS t LIMIT 1
14/05/13 07:18:53 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce
14/05/13 07:18:53 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Found hadoop core jar at: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/hadoop-core.jar
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/e6582e332bf9e0eedfb641f14d866599/foo.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/05/13 07:18:56 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/e6582e332bf9e0eedfb641f14d866599/foo.jar
14/05/13 07:18:56 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of foo
14/05/13 07:18:59 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/05/13 07:19:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/05/13 07:19:00 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/05/13 07:19:00 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201405081447_0046
14/05/13 07:19:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/05/13 07:19:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201405081447_0046_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java
14/05/13 07:19:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201405081447_0046_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java
14/05/13 07:19:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201405081447_0046_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Can't export data, please check task tracker logs
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1    a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java
```

==

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Before performing the export did you check if the hive table is showing the results properly. Can you check by selecting id from test table displays only the id ? it looks like the field delimiter is not set properly in the input file.

Comment: yes I checked in hive table and there is data. I did select id from hive table. any suggestion?

Comment: When you check, please do NOT use select **\*** from test. Instead select id,name from test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location into which you placed the file does not appear to be correct. For a table "test"  you should put a file underneath a **directory**  test.  But your command

```
hadoop fs -put test /user/cloudera
```

creates a **file** called test.

You would likely find more success as follows:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/cloudera/test
hadoop dfs -put test /user/cloudera/test
```